# openjdk shows proper application icon only when started from terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, java

I'm using openJDK on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have strange problem with starting GUI applications that are packed in jar archive. When I start application from terminal with "java -jar archivename.jar" it shows proper application icon in side panel. But when I start it from nautilus by double clicking archive icon it shows standard Duke icon.

It also shows icon when I start application by double-clicking shell script from nautilus.
Script content is simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar archievename.jar
```

Is this some bug, or what is the problem? How can I make it show application icon when started from nautilus too, but without script?

It's not big problem to be honest, because I think that using script to start application is often way to do it in linux, even for native applications, written in C++.
I'm just curious.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make a desktop entry and set the icon properly. See [this question about running a jar file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click#192929).